# NoReverseMatch at /profile/preview/ when argument contains special character or space

Tags: python, django

Getting NoReverseMatch at /profile/preview/ only when argument contains special character or space. for argument without special character or space works fine

`return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile-by-username', kwargs={'username': c.username}))`

`url(r'^preview/(?P<id>\d+)/?$', views.preview, name='profile-preview')`

Comment: You posted `profile-preview` while you redirect to `profile-by-username`

Comment: problem is only for if username contains special character or space.

Comment: What is the special character that is causing you problems ?

Comment: here are some: @ $ * _

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to fix your regex in URL for accepting special characters `@ $ * _`, like this:

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<username>[-\w.@+*$ -]+)/?$', views.user, name='profile-by-username')
```

You can test out this regex in here: https://regex101.com/r/U2lVxj/1

Comment: can you share what is the value of username?

Comment: Yes. It is pr@tik.

Comment: ERROR: ```Reverse for 'profile-by-username' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'username': u'pr@tik'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<username>[\\w\\._\\s-]+)/?$']```

Comment: the regex in the url(as per error) and the regex I have provided(`[-\w.@+*$ -]`) aren't same.